# Can a Yocto recipe be built using the SDK?

Tags: yocto

I have a Yocto project that takes quite some time to compile. The final image is meant to run my application and as such, I have a custom recipe in my own layer.

Since building the whole Yocto image takes a couple of ours, I do build an SDK so I can cross-compile my application and transfer the binary to the running device for testing.

Instead of compiling the binary and having to transfer it manually to the device,
can I use the Yocto recipe I've written for my application with the SDK so that I can "call" its `do_package()`? If other devs could build the `.deb` (assuming `PACKAGE_CLASSES = "package_deb"` in `local.conf`) simply from the SDK that could simplify greatly our workflow.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know that isn't possible, but instead you could setup a yocto environment on a build server and let the other devs run "bitbake <your-package>"

Comment: The initial build process will take several hours the first time you run it. Subsequent builds will run much faster (less then a minute) since a lot of the build will be cached.

Comment: The goal is to _not_ have to rebuild everything. Some devs are working inside a VM, so rebuilding yocto is out of the question, even though they want to build our code sometimes. As for the shared build server, we do have that, but it doesn't scale. Only one `bitbake` (per git clone of the project) can run at any time, or have multiple clone duplicating disk space and time. I just want to compile our own code, not the whole yocto distro...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Huh, bluelightning beat me to the punch. That'll teach me for not hitting refresh. Anyhoo, here's my 2¢:

Yes, have a look at [devtool](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#using-devtool-in-your-workflow). The goal of the devtool script is to improve and simplify the development of software for target devices.

First, have your developers install the extensible SDK ([eSDK](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/sdk-manual/sdk-manual.html#sdk-extensible)), which is built using this command:

```
bitbake -c populate_sdk_ext my-image-name
```

Once you source this SDK, run these commands:

```
devtool modify my-recipe-name
...make your changes to [sdk]/workspace/source/my-recipe-name...
devtool build my-recipe-name
devtool package my-recipe-name
```

This should produce a package of your app in [sdk]/tmp/deploy/rpm/[arch]/my-recipe-name, which can then be deployed to the target machine.

Also, have a look at `devtool deploy-target` if your target machine has network connectivity.

If you give me some more details on your setup I may be able to help more. Hope this at least gets you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I needed. I already have my recipe written, I mainly need a way to build it without having previously built the whole image. `devtool build my-recipe-name` seems to be exactly what I need. Unfortunately I have trouble making it work. I get `cannot touch [...]/qt.conf`. If I create the directory in `meta-qt5/classes/populate_sdk_qt5_base.bbclass`, the sdk builds, but fails to install with `SDK preparation failed`. The log shows errors with python+cmake, `ambiguous redirect` and an `apt-native` configure error. Could be because I'm on jethro and old `meta-qt5`...

Answer (score 2):

This is really what the Extensible SDK is designed to do - provide a pre-built and pre-configured environment and allow you to build applications and other components in pretty much the same way they are built with the full build system. You can even deploy output files over to the target device easily if an ssh server is running on the target.

You can build the extensible SDK with the following command:

```
bitbake -c populate_sdk_ext <imagename>
```

For more information you may wish to read the new [SDK manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/sdk-manual/sdk-manual.html#sdk-extensible).